# Spring Boot and Apache2 on the same server and port

Tags: apache, spring-boot, server

I am looking for solution to enable Apache2 and spring boot application on the same port and server. Boot Application is turn on 
through the internal tomcat server. Apache ( wordpress) should work on port 443 or 80 and main url should be: https://domian.dd/blog. Rest of urls should be processed by Spring Boot.

First problem is that I cannot open two application on the same port.
Second problem is that Spring Boot has configutaion to forwarding port 80 to  443.

Thanks.

Comment: Indeed you cannot have two processes listening on the same port. You need to configure one of both as the frontend server which relays requests to the other server listening on another port or on a socket in the file system. You can also use a pure frontend server like a load balancer and operate _both_ your application servers behind it. How to configure the apache http server for such a task is well documented, take a look at the documentation of its proxy module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not run two application on same port on same machine but you can achieve what you are looking for by following way.

1. Run your spring boot application with path like https://localhost:8443/myapp
2. Run apache and installed ssl
3. Make below settings in ssl.conf to forward your my app traffic to spring boot app

   ```
   SSLProxyEngine on
   SSLProxyVerify none
   SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
   SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
   SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPass /myapp https://localhost:8443/myapp
   ProxyPassReverse /myapp https://localhost:8443/myapp
   ```
4. Put your blog site under apache root folder/blog if `/var/www/html` is root folder then blog would be under `/var/www/html/blog`